# Приложение в эмуляторе Android Studio запускается с некорректным размером

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

Создаю приложение с разрешением 1280 x 720, на desktop лаунчере запускается нормально. Когда пытаюсь запустить на эмуляторе смартфона с разрешением 1920х1080, то разрешение становится не полным. Как сделать так, чтобы приложение в разрешении 1280 х 720 растягивалось на весь экран?

**Edit.**

Использую Libgdx
[image: Приложение]

Comment: Код покажите где изображение показывается

Comment: Собственно, в desktop launcher я указал config.height = 720; и
config.width = 1280; , как это сделать на андроид лаунчере - не знаю. Использую libgdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В андроид лаунчере ничего не нужно указывать.
В классе игры game, который implements Screen в конструкторе создаём камеру:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);
```

А в методе render сразу после public void render(float delta) { пишем:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1); // цвет фона, если ничего нет на экране
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // очищаем экран
camera.update();   // сообщает камере, что нужно обновить матрицы.
game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); // приводим наш SpriteBatch к координатам (и соответственно к размерам) камеры
```

Таким образом, используя камеру, мы не привязываемся физически к размеру экрана устройства. Он может быть как больше 1280х720, так и меньше. Но отображаться изображения будут всегда правильно.